# pass an array from a child to parent ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an array in a component i want to export it or pass it to other component (parent)

child component :

```
export default function child(){

const arr = ["1020","52214","3325"]
return (
<div> child</div>
)
}
```

parent :

```
export default function parent(){

return (
<>
<div> parent</div>
<child/>
</>
)
}
```

Comment: Put the array in the parent https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In react we don't pass values from child to parent but the other way around: it's a one-way data flow!

You can `useState` to create a stateful value and a set-function in the parent, pass the `set` function to the child and allow it to set the value.

Example:

```
export default function child(props){

const arr = ["1020","52214","3325"];
props.setMyArray(arr);

return (
<div> child</div>
)
}
```

---

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function parent(){
  const [myArray, setArray] = useState([]);

  return (
    <>
    <div> parent</div>
    <child setMyArray={setArray}/>
    </>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass data from child to parent.

You can pass like this.

```
const ParentPage = () => {

  const [arr , setArr ] = useState([])
  console.log(arr)  // [1,2,3]

  return (
    <ChildPage setArr={setArr} />
  );
}

const ChildPage = ({setArr}) => {
    return (
        <button onClick={()=> setArr([1,2,3]) }}> </button>
    );
}
```

or you can do with `redux`

Answer (score 0):

You can use props to call a function in the parent element and pass an argument in the function from the child element.

Here's an example:

Child element:

```
export default function child(props){

const [arr,setarr]= useState(["1020","52214","3325"]);

return (
<div onclick={()=>{props.func(arr)}}> child</div>
)
}
```

Parent element:

```
export default function parent(){
 
function passvalue(arr){
   const passedvalue = arr; 
}


return (
<>
<div> parent</div>
<child func={passvalue}/>
</>
)
}
```